# Verilog - If Condition

Tags: if-statement, binary, switch-statement, logic, verilog

I am having an issue with this module in Verilog when compiling on Quartus Prime V16.0. The objective is to return a output a specific 8-bit number [00011000] if any single bit out of 8 total input bits is a 1. Does this if statement work? If not, what is a better method of implementation? Does the operator work this way in returning a 1? From what I've researched it does.

The inputs to the or operator are 4-bit A (in[7:4]) and 4-bit B (in[3:0])

```
module case3 (in, out);

input [7:0] in;
output [7:0] out;
wire x, y;

assign x = 1;

if (x == or(y, in[7:4], in[3:0]))
    assign out[7:0] = 8'b00011000;

endmodule
```

The function call in my main module looks like this:

```
case3 u3(
    .in(SW[7:0]),
    .out(wire3)
);
```

Wire3 is a wire variable defined to retrieve the output from the Case3 module for further usage.

Comment: It's hard to know even where to start here but I'd recommend going back to your textbook and reviewing 1) Usage of Verilog primitives (your 'or' there) 2) Usage of assign statements 3) always blocks.  Finally your problem statement is incomplete.  What happens when the input is all 0s?  There are other logical problems even if this were legal syntax.

Comment: just adding to Brian's comment, please review your terminology as well, `case3` is **not** a function. So, start reading about verilog hdl concept first. it is **not** a generic programming language.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following code for your purpose.

```
module case3 (in, out);

input [7:0] in;
output [7:0] out;

assign out[7:0] = (|in) ? 8'b00011000 : <Else Case>;

endmodule
```

Here `|in` will do `or`ing of all bits of the `in` and will return a single bit output. So if any of the bit of `in` is `1`, then `|in` will return `1`.

Answer (score 0):

As the above comments say, it is difficult to even know where to start. So, I'm going to answer this question in the hope that by my answering it you will get some guidance about where you should be going. If this is homework, then congratulations! - I've done your homework for you. Whether it is or not, if your intention is to learn Verilog, then you will need to try to understand why it is written as it is.

So, assuming you specification is

> The objective is to return a output a specific 8-bit number [00011000] if any single bit out of 8 total input bits is a 1.

I think something like this will do the trick:

```
module case3 (in, out);  // This is very old-fashioned syntax. Since 2001, we've been writing
  input [7:0] in;        //   module case3 (input [7:0] in, output reg [7:0] out);
  output [7:0] out;      // 'out' must be a 'reg'. By default outputs are wires and it is 
  reg[7:0] out;          // illegal to assign to a wire from an 'always' block

  always @(*)            // 'if' is illegal outside an 'initial' block or an 'always' block. 
                         // Verilog is NOT a programming language, it is a HARDWARE DESCRIPTION
                         // language. Lines inside a 'module' are NOT executed sequentially,
                         // but concurrently, ie all at once, just like hardware.
                         // Lines inside an 'initial' or 'always' block are executed sequentially:
                         // think of an 'always' block is "a little bit of software that models
                         // a little bit of hardware".

    if (in)              // if 'in' is non-zero, Verilog considers it to be 'true'

      out = 8'b00011000; // don't say 'assign' - it is legal here, but means something weird
                         // and there is no need to say out[7:0]
    else
      out =              // who knows? You didn't say.

endmodule
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this. (How could I? There's a bit missing.)

Comment: @Serge out is a reg, not a wire. Look at line 4 of my code.